# Silverlight controls with xaml - resource consumption

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, resources, silverlight-5.0

I am facing memory consumption issue in Silverlight 5 app.

After a few days of measuring, i've seen that the main memory consumers are custom UserControls (with xaml), and that those controls stand out from the rest of controls that do not have xaml (e.g. inherited from System.Windows.Controls.TextBox (System.Windows.Controls.Control)).

I was surprised to find out that when Silverlight control calls `InitializeComponent();`(constructor), Framework is calling `System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object, Uri)` *every time* in order to get xaml.

So, if you are creating 500 controls dynamically (same type), Framework will call `LoadComponent()` 500 times? I expected that xaml would be loaded only when control is being instantiated for the first time, and no more `LoadComponent()` after that.

My questions are:

- Is it possible to turn on some kind of ,,caching mechanism'' in Silverlight, so that when some UserControl is instantiated, Framework recognizes that xaml was loaded before and not to do the same thing again loads xaml only the first time?
- Is there some other mechanism or good practice to avoid loading of same xaml every time?

I have basic example with mentioned kinds of controls. You can find code example below. 
This is just a basic example, without any Binding, DataContext objects, Dependency properties and so on.

*Controls*

**МyTextBox.cs** that inherits from System.Windows.Controls.TextBox

```
   using System.Windows.Controls;

    namespace TestControls.Controls
    {
        public class МyTextBox : TextBox
        {

            public МyTextBox()
            {
                Text = "MyTextBox";
            }
        }
    }
```

**MyText.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestControls.Controls.MyText"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <TextBlock Name="Text"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MyText.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestControls.Controls
{
    public partial class MyText : UserControl
    {
        public MyText()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Text.Text = "MyTextControl";
        }
    }
}
```

*App*

**MainPage.xaml**

```
 <UserControl x:Class="TestControlsApplication.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <StackPanel Name="Panel"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using TestControls.Controls;

namespace TestControlsApplication
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                MyText t = new MyText();
                МyTextBox tb = new МyTextBox();
                Panel.Children.Add(t);
                Panel.Children.Add(tb);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MyText control (that has xaml) allocates 5,1 MB (all instances) and MyTextBox that inherits System.Windows.Controls.TextBox has allocated 0,4 MB.

[image: Memory allocation (Jetbrains dot trace)]

Similar thing is when we are comparing instantiating time of two controls.

[image: Trace - calls number and execution time]

Comment: If you create control fully in code behind, then it doesn't need to load anything. Otherwise it must create all controls specified in xaml, set their properties, etc. this is why it reads it every time. Think of xaml as a ToDo list for the control. To create instance you need such list: either as code or as a xaml, right?

Comment: Another point is what you are creating same control 1000 times. Normally you don't have so many. Use list controls (`ListBox`, `ListView`, etc.) they support virtualization and will only create controls for currently visible items, saving you a lot of memory and time.

Comment: @Sinatr : First question: Yes, that is an option - to implement control without xaml - fully in code behind, as you said. But i am trying to avoid it (i have more than one control with this kind of issues) and see if there is a magic on/off button in SL (or WPF) to do the ,,caching'' of xaml. I did not find an answer during my investigation, that is why i'm asking. :)

Comment: @Sinatr : Second point: Virtualization is implemented on places where this kind of presentation is available. In some parts of application (business app) large amount of data should be presented to user, so therefore all those controls are instantiated at some point. If i have large amount of controls (with xaml) that consume 12-13 times more resources that similar controls (just without xaml), virtualization is just a tip of the iceberg.